# R : how to combine three distribution curves into one curve and export the dataset

Tags: r

There are three datasets with different data length and each with their own distribution and mean. How can I combine three datasets into one curve and then export the dataset?

```
a <- rnorm(8000, 53.2, 1.9)
b <- rnorm(9000, 59.3, 0.8)
c <- rnorm(1000, 37.1, 0.6)

aHistogram <- hist(a)
bHistogram <- hist(b)
cHistogram <- hist(c)
```

How to combine three curves to one curve and export the dataset?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you mean `hist(c(a,b,c))`??

Comment: Thank you! R is a good tool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
df <-data.frame(values=c(a,b,c))
```